# Form Validation and Submission problem in PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation, http-redirect

I am newbie and I am trying to simple form submission with validation (not tidy validation).
My PHP code is here:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<title>Form Handling</title>
<body>

<h1>Contact Form</h1>
<form name="form1" action="contact_val.php" method="POST">
Name <input type="text" name="fname"><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

$fname = $_POST['fname'];

if (!isset($fname) or empty($fname)){

    echo "Please enter name!";


  }


}
?>
```

I just want to know how to redirect on this page again if input is blank and submit button clicked otherwise go to action page.

Comment: You can use header() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to redirect.

Comment: Are you just asking how to redirect in PHP?  A quick Google search would find that.  It's not clear from the description what isn't working here.

Comment: you can use this link, https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp

Comment: @Ved 
I show that link it all things are perfect for me... but I want to redirect on the other page not PHP_SELF... got it my point?

Comment: header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

Comment: Got it!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can seperate the this File into two file. html based content with ".html", php tag contetn with ".php", then write php file.

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){ 
   $fname = $_POST['fname']; 
if (!isset($fname) or empty($fname)){ 
    echo "Please enter name!"; 
  } 
header("location: (html page url)");
} 
?> 
Write this code